# Choosing the good initial value of the Newton-Raphson iteration method for Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, parameterization, optimization

I want to estimate the four parameters of **Exponentiated Modified Weibull Extension (EMWE)** distribution introduced by *Sarhan and Apaloo (2013)* with the Maximum Likelihood Estimation. Because the first derivative of the log-likelihood function of the four parameters give implicit solutions then I tried to continue with the Newton-Raphson iteration method. It's just that I am not familiar in determining the good initial value for this method. Does anyone know how to determine the good initial value for the Newton-Raphson iteration method? Are there any special requirements in determining this value?